# Intercept Response Body Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm searching to intercept response body / response text using Electron.
Example:

```js
// My Request Interceptor,
....onHeaderReceived(..., {

    const responseBody = details.responseText;
    console.log(responseBody); 

});
```

And I will get the response of the request (in my console)

```json
{
 "userid":1929192192,
 "username":"Stanley",
 "courses_count":19,
 "teachers_count": 12
}
```

I searched in the documentation and I didn't found.

Can somebody help me?

Regards

- Stan

Comment: is [this](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request#webrequestonheadersreceivedfilter-listener) the method you're looking for?

Comment: @pushkin I seached here but there not responseText or something look like

Comment: is `responseHeaders` not what you want?

Comment: @pushkin Oh yes thanks you're the best !